# How to programmatically select a row in a table

Tags: ios, uitableview, select, random, row

I have a table which is viewed by the user. As the user shakes his device, I want a random row to be selected. How do I do this?

I have the shake gesture recognized, I can create an random integer that doesn't exceed the list count, but I can't find the right code to have that row highlighted in the table.

In Apple's documentation I found:

```
NSIndexPath *rowToSelect;  // assume this exists and is set properly
UITableView *myTableView;  // assume this exists

[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:rowToSelect animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone;
[myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:rowToSelect atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNon animate:YES];
```

but I can't get it working. I have a `UITableView *myTableView`. I have used the randomized integer as the rowToSelect.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to read the FAQ, and check your code formatting in your posts before hitting the submit button.

Comment: The only reason the code you provided wouldn't work (assuming the index path is correct) is that your table view is nil.

Comment: That is assuming you have the typos corrected in the actual code too.

Comment: This line by itself is enough to select a row and scroll to it `[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:rowToSelect animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];` If this line is not doing that then post the results of this statment `NSLog(@"myTableView = %@ / rowToSelect = %@",myTableView,rowToSelect);`

Comment: My intuition is that this line indeed would be enough. But rowtoSelect is no integer, it is an NSIndexPath and I think I would have to implement that. Still, what else than a number can be given as the argument rowToSelect??

Comment: This does the job of setting an indexpath right. (randomrij is randomrow, eentabelview is atableview)
 
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:randomRij inSection:0];
[[self eenTabelView] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
 
Still nothing changes in the view, the row isn't made active.
 
Should there be extra code to make it happen or is there something wrong with these two lines of code given here.
 
For example, do there exist multiple NSindexPaths and did I set some virtual IndexPath to the random row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I got it working. I kept the following line:

```
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:randomRij inSection:0];
```

I added the following lines:

```
[eenTabelView selectRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

I commented the following line:

```
//[[self eenTabelView] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Important rule: all UI changes must be done in Main Thread.
Add

```
if (![NSThread isMainThread])
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:_cmd withObject:(%YOUR_OBJECT_TAKEN_IN_THIS_SELECTOR) waitUntilDone:Yes];
}
```

before your code to run it already in main thread OR (more correct variant) extract all your UI changes to separate method and call it in main thread.

Example:

```
-(void)yourSelector
{
…
    UI changes
…
}

-(IBOutlet)yourAction
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourSelector) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:Yes];
}
```

Comment: That doesn't have any relevance to what he's doing. The table must be nil.

Comment: Why not relevance? He generate random rows and want to select one. If table nil it'll be impossible to select anything :)

Comment: Fine, it has some relevance :) But this method is overly complicated. Just call `yourSelector` from the main thread.

Comment: This does the job of setting an indexpath right. (randomrij is randomrow, eentabelview is atableview)
 
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:randomRij inSection:0];
[[self eenTabelView] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
 
Still nothing changes in the view, the row isn't made active.
 
Should there be extra code to make it happen or is there something wrong with these two lines of code given here.
 
For example, do there exist multiple NSindexPaths and did I set some virtual IndexPath to the random row.